# Typescript auto-completion in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, code-completion

Using VS2015, in C# or other languages when you type part of an identifier, then punctuation, it auto-completes. eg type 'conso' then '.' and it will complete it to 'Console.'. I like this!

But in Typescript, I have to press enter or tab to get the completion. So 'docum' then enter then '.', to get 'document.'

Is there a config option to make the Typescript completion work like C#? The difference is annoying.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like at the moment this is not supported, but it is a [known issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/315).

> this will be fixed in 2.0. autocompletion on most characters...

Following the trail leads me [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9424).

Where I found

> I have a fix for this, and it should be part of the final 2.0 release.

Comment: That's great thanks. Same behavior in VS Code, and unlike Microsoft to be so inconsistent (it works perfectly for SQL, for example). Didn't Anders say 2.0 was due in June..?!

Comment: @user826840 You're welcome, and I haven't heard him say it. It is in beta though: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/07/11/announcing-typescript-2-0-beta/  and there aren't any due dates here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/milestones =/

Comment: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/B881 at 43:30 he says "[should be out in ] late May or June". I shouldn't watch those videos they make me impatient for new features!

Comment: @user826840 Thank you :-) I guess we'll just have to be patient a bit longer ^^ (btw, do you mind accepting this as the correct answer, as it seems it is correct for the time being) ;)